# FFMPEG command to replace first 32 bytes of mp4 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

Is there any utility or command in ffmpeg to replace first 32 bytes of video mp4 file from another key file containing 32 bytes data?

Comment: Try something like `dd conv=notrunc bs=1 count=32 if=input.mp4 of=output.mp4`

Comment: Excellent!.Thank you so much. It Works :) @DaBler